# Moving Position of Div

Tags: css, html, web, styling

I'm making a website using dreamweaver with a html and css style sheet.

I have a "top content" div and a "menu" div" underneath that.

Currently there is a space between them. How do I make it so that there is no space and the "menu" div is immediately below it?

Thanks

Comment: Please supply the community with the code you have so far.

Comment: In your browser, inspect the elements, look for `margin` properties etc. You should probably use a `reset css` file to zero out the browser defaults. Also, it would be beneficial to actually post your `HTML` and `CSS`

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is turn into html code view and define the margin property to be 0.

For example:

```
.topContent, .menu {
margin: 0;
}
```